# How to grab data from one tab and paste it to another tab using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to grab some data from a page opened in one tab, and paste it into a textarea of another page opened in another browser tab. How can I do this with Javascript and Greasemonkey?

Comment: I don't think that you can pass around data between tabs with only javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Set both domains in the metadata block so the script will be activated on both pages
2. Find an unique element in both websites from which you can detect which page you are currently on.
3. If you are on the page with the table, get the data and put it with `GM_setValue` in the store. If needed, open the next website by using `GM_openInTab`.
4. If the next website gets detected, retrieve the stored value with `GM_getValue` and paste it into the textarea.

Not this hard over Greasemonkey, even though its necessary to load the textarea-page AFTER the table-page.

**Example**

```
// @include       http://website1.com/*
// @include       http://website2.com/*
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $("#divfromsite1").length )
    {
       GM_setValue("pastetext", $("#gettable").html() );
       GM_openInTab("http://website2.com/");
    }
    else
    {
       $("#pastetextarea").val( GM_getValue("pastetext","") );
    }
});
```

Comment: Examples get more upvotes (hint).  Also, the question is very poor.  It could be that a simple AJAX request is all that is needed.

Comment: I'm here to answer questions, not deliver a show for everyone. If the user is able to do his code with this instructions, thats fine. Also, me and LeviBothelo simply took him literally about the pasting into the textarea.

Comment: @BrockAdams Added an example now anyway :P

Comment: Okay +1. That'll work with the level of detail the OP supplied, **except** you use jQuery and don't show how to include jQuery in the script.  (This question was not jQuery related, and the OP is doubtless a newbie to GM.)

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to do. It isn't impossbile, but it is indeed quite difficult.

Cross document messaging is a way of passing messages from one page to another using JavaScript. The first prerequisite for this is that the documents must have the same origin. That means that they must come fromt the same port on the same domain and must share the same protocol. Where it works well is when you have one page nested in an `iframe` inside another. When this is the case, you can do the following:

1. get the `window` object of the nested page, add an event listener to the `receiveMessage` event.
2. Use `window[name].postMessage(msg, url)` to send a message to the other window.
3. Capture the `data` property of the message event, which will contain the information that you sent.

What makes your case difficult is that you want to communicate across tabs. I will say that I have no experience in doing XDM across tabs, and personally believe that if you have an application running across multiple tabs that need to interact with one another that maybe you need to review your application design... users might not like you changing things in their browser that they probably cannot immediately see and thus understand.

Anyways, if you want to go ahead with this you need to look at how different browsers give you access to their tabs. For Firefox you might want to start at this post [Get window object from tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609753/get-window-object-from-tab), and for Chrome you may want to start here [How do I get the window object for a specific tab if I have that tab's tabId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822133/how-do-i-get-the-window-object-for-a-specific-tab-if-i-have-that-tabs-tabid).

---

Given that the question has been edited and the use of Greasemonkey has been added, this may or may not meet your needs, and unfortunately I am not skilled enough in Greasemonkey to give you a GM-based solution. If you need help with a solution using XDM I'll be happy to assist.

Comment: how bout if m planning to use greasmonkey ?? 

would that decrease the difficulty level ? also i forgot to mention that both the pages belong to same domain ..

Comment: I don't know greasemonkey so I can't say, but I don't think that you can get around working with the browser APIs. You need to really think if this is going to add significant value to your application... often in programming if something is too difficult it is because there is a better way.

Comment: the reason i asked this was because, almost half of my works requires me to copy paste data between two tabs from same domain, i could not think of any other option apart from greasemonkey . please suggest if u have something that u think will help my resolve my issue.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to this question!  It's a Greasemonkey scenario, the OP can't restructure the page to add iframes.  The linked answers also do not apply; they are for *extension* API's.  The OP is not asking about writing an extension, nor does he need to.  Greasemonkey can solve his problem, but the details depend mightily on details the OP has omitted.

Comment: @BrockAdams - The question was **not** tagged Greasemonkey when I posted, nor was Greasemonkey mentioned in the question. Look at the edit log. I interpreted the suggestion for Greasemonkey in his comment as a possibility, but did not know that he had already implemented it in his setup. It is up to the OP to be specific, not the person giving the answer to read his mind.

Comment: @LeviBotelho: Yes, I saw that the question had been edited after your answer and did not downvote the answer.  In reread, my earlier comment had a harsher tone than I intended.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries :) No harm, no foul.

Comment: m sorry, i should have been more specific about my thoughts and question. 

i apologize , will keep a check on it !!